How to automatically install dependencies of nested packages in Python?
I have a package called "library". The directory structure looks like this:
-library

    +src

        *pkg1.py

        *pkg2.py

-pyproject.toml

-__init__.py

The pyproject.toml contains:
[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools"]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"

[project]
name = "library"
version = "0.0.1"
dependencies = [pkg1,pkg2]

My understanding is that in pyproject.toml I can specify dependencies. However, pkg1 and pkg2 both have their own dependencies. How do I make it so that these dependencies automatically install when installing the library.whl?
